# Python Programming: Automated Backup of network devices independent of device platform (Cisco Juniper Fortigate Checkpoint)

Tags: python

```
import telnetlib
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import time
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
username = "*****"
password = "******"
buff = ''
resp = ''
with open('Fetch.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:
            ip = line
            result = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "2", "-w", "1000", ip],
                                      stdout=limbo,
                                      stderr=limbo).wait()
            if result:
                print ip, "Link Down - Site unreachable"
                f = open('DownSites.txt', 'a+')
                f.write( line + '\n' )
                f.close()
            else:
                try:
                    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(line)
                    tn.read_until("Username:")
                    tn.write(username+"\n")
                    tn.read_until("Password:")
                    tn.write(password+"\n")
                    tn.write("terminal length 0"+"\n")
                    tn.write("sh ver"+"\n")
                    tn.write("sh processes cpu history"+"\n")
                    tn.write("sh run"+"\n")
                    tn.write("exit"+"\n")
                    output=tn.read_all()
                    print ip, "Reachable ~ Command Executed"
                    tn.close()
                    fp=open(line + '.txt',"w")
                    fp.write(output)
                    fp.close()
                except Exception as e:
                    print ip, "ERROR: ", e
```

This is the very Program im trying to run using pycharm community edition compiler in order to backup configuration files of networkdevices independent of manufacturer.The error that pops up during compilation is **Byte code generated should be an object not STR** .Kindly help me through or if there is a better code than this out there kindly do let me know the same.

Comment: I tried to fix your missing indentation. did I do it right?

Comment: also you stomp on `Fetch.txt` when you open `DownSites.txt` as `f`. I don't think this is the "byte code" issue, but I'd change it if I were you.

Comment: Aaron you are welcome to modify my code.Please do share your changes on the code and please do post the modified code.your idea will be of help.

Comment: I would just change `f = open('DownSites.txt', 'a+')` to some other variable like: `down = open('DownSites.txt', 'a+')` (and also the next two lines as well).

Comment: also, what compilation are you doing? cython? python is not normally compiled.